# json to xml transformation with x2js

Tags: geojson, xml, json

I am trying to transform a JSON object to XML, but i have somehow get stuck in jscript (not an expert). Here is the code:

```
...
var GEOJSON_PARSER = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
var vectorLayerAsJson = GEOJSON_PARSER.write(vlayer.features);
    ...
var x2js = new X2JS();
    ...
var xmlDocStr2 = x2js.json2xml_str(vectorLayerAsJson);
alert(xmlDocStr2);
    ...
// JSON arrays to string
var xmlDoc1 = x2js.json2xml_str({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [22580, -24812],
                    [24772, -28076],
                    [27732, -24204],
                    [22580, -24812]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
});
alert(xmlDoc1);
```

In the first case the json2xml_str(vectorLayerAsJson) function returns something like a JSON object however in the second it returns the correct XML.

Both objects are identical "vectorLayerAsJson" is the one declared as `"type":"FeatureCollection ..."` in the second case.

I have also tried alternate ways of calling `x2js.json2xml_str` such as `x2js.json2xml_str($.parseJSON($("vectorLayerAsJson").val()));` with no success!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not aware Openlayers 2 is already able to write your features to XML based formats, so I'm not sure using x2js is useful (but I don't know your use case)

It can be KML, GPX, GML v2, GML v3. Those are all subsets of XML.

Read the [API docs](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GML/v2-js.html) for more.

You can see a sample using your code to create GML (you can also look at [Vector Formats Example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/vector-formats.html))

```
var gml_parser_v2 = new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v2();
var gml_parser_v3 = new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v3();

vector_layer_as_gml_v2 = gml_parser_v2.write(vlayer.features);
vector_layer_as_gml_v3 = gml_parser_v3.write(vlayer.features);

console.log(vector_layer_as_gml_v2);
console.log(vector_layer_as_gml_v3);
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your json file is well formed? try here http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.Uql7VyeQMRc and verify first that the conversion works correctly.

Comment: If i alert my initial Json file, copy and paste its contents to this online tool, there is no problem!

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure you don't have an [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) into your file.
A one-liner command available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom) can spot and suppress it.

Another option could be switching to another js lib conversion such as [JSONXML](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/).

(If you want further support, please upload file and code online)